# Using ChaplinJS in Django project

Tags: javascript, django, coffeescript, chaplinjs

I'm trying to build ChaplinJS in Django project. I've downloaded [Chaplin Boilerplate](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin-boilerplate) and opened **index.html** in browser. Worked perfectly fine (showed chaplin example page). Then i put all files into Django project "front-end" dir and resolved all paths to *.js libs in index.html via django's **staticfiles**. When i open my page from localhost now i'm getting just empty screen. Server console shows:

```
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:53]"GET /books/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1542
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:53]"GET /front-end/books/bower_components/requirejs/require.js/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82687
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:53]"GET /front-end/books/js/routes.js HTTP/1.1" 200 185
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:53]"GET /front-end/books/js/application.js HTTP/1.1" 200 802
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:54]"GET /front-end/books/bower_components/chaplin/chaplin.js HTTP/1.1" 200 90223
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:54]"GET /front-end/books/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 242142
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:54]"GET /front-end/books/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js HTTP/1.1" 200 229855
[11/Jun/2015 21:34:54]"GET /front-end/books/bower_components/backbone/backbone.js HTTP/1.1" 200 60127
```

Also i checked JS console in browser: Application object is created, but none Controllers or Views. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. Everything was fine except URL. In Django project i had **books** application, so URL to index page was `localhost:8000/books/` but in Chaplin routes **match** was set on `match '', 'hello#show'` so changing it to `match 'books', 'hello#show'` solves the problem